# Trim values while exporting WPF DataGrid to CSV

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am exporting WPF DataGrid values to CSV with following code:

```
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid1.SelectAllCells();
        DataGrid1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, DataGrid1);
        DataGrid1.UnselectAllCells();
        String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
        File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + @"\" + "AllCustomersCSV.txt", result, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8);
    }
```

However result has a lot of spaces after values. Looks like WPF DataGrid behavior. I have tried to add:

```
String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue.Trim());
```

but it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I guess it should be done with loop or List as it is not able to trim each one separately in my current setup?

---

**EDIT 1:**

Here is an example of txt file output:

[image]

---

**EDIT 2:**

`result` output example:

```
\tENERGIDIRETORAT                    \t                                   \tBOX 5091 MAJORSTUA                 \tN-0301
```

I guess I need something like:

```
result = Regex.Replace(result, " *\t *", ",");
```

However this is not functioning for all rows, especially with empty cells in some rows.

So it should remove all whitespaces (tabs) before `\t` but leave `\t`'s to be replaced by `,` (commas).

---

**EDIT 3:**

I haven't got CSV export working as there were some commas probably missing, because after importing it to Excel some columns did not match. I went for trying xls file format. This seems to be working fine (UTF8 Encoding was wrong BTW):

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid2.SelectAllCells();
        DataGrid2.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, DataGrid2);
        String resultat = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
        String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        DataGrid2.UnselectAllCells();
        StreamWriter file1 = new StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + @"\" + "SameCustomersCSV.xls",
    false, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
        file1.WriteLine(result.Replace(',', ' '));
        file1.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(" Exporting data to Excel file to your Desktop is ready!");
    }
```

I don't really understand what is the problem with CSV...

Comment: Try to debug the `DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue` value using quick watch and then the complete value `(string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue)`. Maybe `(string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue).Trim();` will work.

Comment: Please, share the example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the tabs by iterating through the copied characters and write all of them except `\t` to the file:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid1.SelectAllCells();
    DataGrid1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
    ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, DataGrid1);
    DataGrid1.UnselectAllCells();

    string result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + @"\" + "AllCustomersCSV.txt",
        false, Encoding.UTF8))
        foreach (char c in result)
            if (c != '\t')
                sw.Write(c);
            else
                sw.Write(",");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It gives an error `The name 'DataGrid1_CopyingRowClipboardContent' does not exist in the current context Liinos inspector FilterTest`

Comment: @hatman: Sorry, that line shouldn't be there :) I removed it.

Comment: I have been already investigating for what it is for? Now I get an error while pressing the button. `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070003
  Message=Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\\bin\Debug\DesktopDirectory\AllCustomersCSV.txt'.` Something wrong with Desktop folder

Comment: @hatman: I copied the file path from your example. You can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, it was about `File.WriteAllText`

Comment: @hatman: `Environment.GetFolderPath` is missing. See my edit.

Comment: @hatman: What's the exact value of `result` when you debug then?

Comment: `result`output in edited section of original question

Answer (score 1):

Strip out the any extra space or tabs before writing the information like this:

```
var rawCSV = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
var result = Regex.Replace(rawCSV, @"\s{2,}|\t", " ");
```

what that does is remove two or more spaces, or an individual tab, and then replace it with a single space.

---

```
var test = "a,   b, c,\t\td   ";

Regex.Replace(test, @"\s{2,}|\t", " ")
```

Replace returns the string  `a, b, c, d`.

Comment: Thanks for this! It is quite close but not there yet as output does not look correct. Basically it looks like all spaces before `\t` should be removed. However it shouldn't remove `\t`'s.Trying to figure out correct syntax.